# Connect to remote API using ColdFusion cfhttp

Tags: json, coldfusion, cfhttp

I am trying to connect to the emma api using ColdFusion. Using the below code. [Trying to get a listing of all members in an account](http://api.myemma.com/api/external/members.html) as per api docs doing the below. I keep getting status code of 404 on the below call. Any ideas on what I am missing here?

```
<cfset account_id= '123'/>
<cfset public_key = 'abc'/>
<cfset private_key = 'xyz' /> 
<cfset the_url = 'https://app.e2ma.net/#account_id#/members/' />

<cfhttp url="#the_url#" method="get" result="Results" timeout="999">
      <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />
      <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="application/json"  />
      <cfhttpparam type="header" name="public_api_key" value="#public_key#" >
      <cfhttpparam type="header" name="private_api_key" value="#private_key#" >
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#Results#"/>
```

Here are the results of the `cfdump`:

[image: cfdump of results variable]

Comment: Try it without a trailing slash on members. Also make sure the account_id you're using is valid. Their documentation is a bit confusing with how they use `#` since it is valid in a URL, however the request you're trying to make is shown without a trailing slash (`GET /#account_id/members`)

Comment: Tried it without trailing slash, still the same. Also I think i have the right url

Comment: I think the public and private api key needs to be sent as a header and not form fields. https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-g-h/cfhttpparam.html

Comment: If you look at their main page they have some examples. This one is PHP however, they're using `api.e2ma.net` instead of `app.e2ma.net`. Here is their example: `$url = "https://api.e2ma.net/".$account_id."/members/add";`.

Comment: Yes lol, using the correct url will definitely help.  I missed that on first glance.  Now you should be able to use the header to do the basic auth

Comment: yes lol from me too, somehow I had app. I was able to connect fine thanks all!

Comment: @user747291 I updated my previously deleted answer (I had put down about escaping `#` due to their documentation including it). New answer is updated to be relevant from the comments made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using the wrong endpoint. In their [documentation](http://api.myemma.com/index.html) they say the following:

> The endpoint for all of our API calls is https://api.e2ma.net/

In your code you're using `app.e2ma.net`, this should be `api.e2ma.net` instead.

Also the path for the URL you're requesting doesn't include a trailing slash in their documentation (`GET /#account_id/members` is what they have). You may also want to update that.

Comment: My vote put your reputation over 1000.  You owe me a beer.